# How to install Turtlebot on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to install Turtlebot on Ubuntu 12.04?
I cannot find any guide on ROS wiki.

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38847/how-to-install-turtlebot-on-ubuntu-12.04/) by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2012-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can install turtlebot using deb packages. The listing of packages can be found using **synaptic**

Also, you can install packages using the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name e.g. ros-fuerte-turtlebot>
```

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0